# How .scale_ is calculated by sklearn in python? (What is it's algorithm exactly?)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, normalization, iqr, standardization

Please, suppose that we have an array like this:

```
import numpy as np
X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                     [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
```

We scale it with `.scale_` existed in `sklearn` by this code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
scaler.scale_
```

and such result was shown:

```
array([0.81649658, 0.81649658, 1.24721913])
```

Are you know how it was calculated?
If you know, please write its formula that how it is calculated?
I supposes that `.scale_` shows `Interquartile range (IQR)`, but when I calculate it manually `IQR` is:

```
array([2, 2, 3]) rather than `array([0.81649658, 0.81649658, 1.24721913])`.
```

Also, I think `array([0.81649658, 0.81649658, 1.24721913])` is a **normal** type of `array([2, 2, 3])`, but I don't know how it was normalized.
Please, help me to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three main statistic measures of mean, variance, and Standard deviation are calculated with

```
mean = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train).mean_ 
variance = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train).var_
Standard_deviation = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train).scale_
```

according to the question:

```
X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                     [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
```

---

```
mean = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train).mean_ 
print(mean)
array([1.        , 0.        , 0.33333333])
```

---

```
variance = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train).var_
print(variance )
array([0.66666667, 0.66666667, 1.55555556])
```

---

```
Standard_deviation = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train).scale_
print(Standard_deviation )
array([0.81649658, 0.81649658, 1.24721913])
```

---

in other words:

```
scaler.scale_ = np.sqrt(scaler.var_)
```